# Hide nav button in react-material-ui-carousel

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I've just implemented the react material ui carousel, and it was pretty straightforward, the only thing i didn't catch, is how to hide buttons and show them only on over.
I noticed the props `navButtonsAlwaysVisible` and set it to false but it isn't enough.
Should i implement my own logic for that, or maybe I'm just missing something?

here's the component code:

```
import styles from '../../styles/Testimonial.module.scss'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Carousel from 'react-material-ui-carousel'

const Testimonial = _ => {
const items = [
        {
            imageUrl: "/png/image0.webp",
            feedback: "feedback0",
            name: "name0",
            location: "location0"
        },
        {
            imageUrl: "/png/image1.jpeg",
            feedback: "feedback1",
            name: "name1",
            location: "location1"
        }
    ]

    return (
        <div id="customers" className={`section ${styles.testimonial}`}>
            <h2 className={`title ${styles.title}`}>Clientes Felizes</h2>
            <span className={"separator"}> </span>

            <Carousel
                className={styles.carousel}
                autoPlay={true}
                stopAutoPlayOnHover={true}
                interval={5000}
                animation={"slide"}
                swipe={true}
                navButtonsAlwaysVisible={false}
                navButtonsProps={{ 
                    style: {
                        backgroundColor: "#8f34eb",
                        opacity: 0.4
                    }
                }} 
            >
                {
                    items.map( (item, i) => <Item key={i} item={item} /> )
                }
            </Carousel>
        </div>
    )
}

function Item(props)
{
    return (
        <article className={styles.testimonial__card}>
            <div className={styles.testimonial__photo_container}>
                <Image
                    className={styles.testimonial__photo}
                    src={props.item.imageUrl}
                    alt="Testimonial"
                    width={312}
                    height={300}
                />
            </div>
            <p className={styles.testimonial__copy}>{props.item.feedback}</p>
            <span className={styles.testimonial__name}>{props.item.name}</span>
            <span className={styles.testimonial__city}>{props.item.location}</span>
        </article>
    )
}

export default Testimonial;
```

Comment: It can be easily hidden by Custom CSS but I need to see your output.

Comment: Currently it s deployed on Meuartelie.com
If custom css is the only way i ll probably hide the button in mobile mode and that's enough since there's a swipe option active

Comment: Like this? https://nimb.ws/5Fy7vE

Comment: ideally navigator should appear on hover

Answer (score 1):

there's a prop called *navButtonsAlwaysInvisible*

```
navButtonsAlwaysInvisible={true}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Custom CSS for your purpose. Based on the current rendered markup,

```
.jss6 {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all ease 1000ms; /* So that it does not disappear quickly */
}
```

You can define the hover for the parent so that it displays only when the parent container is hovered on:

```
.jss1.Testimonial_carousel__3rny3:hover .jss6 {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This is how it works now:

[image]